# Select other image if file image not found

Tags: graphics

I want to edit my code with rule:
If image A.png not found, display backup.png

My minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

Select backup.png image if file image A.png not found
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{A.png}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: If `A.png` should be in your file input path, you could use `\IfFileExists{A.png}{...}{...}`. However, this won't work if `A.png` is only in the path searched for images and set with `\graphicspath`.

Comment: @cfr true although only a matter of locally changing \input@path (which is what `\includegraphics` does anyway to use IfFileExists to check that the file is there before including it.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle True, but I don't know what the OP wants this for, so it seemed to need mentioning.