# Use IfFileExists within macro

Tags: macros

How can `IfFileExists` be used within `\newcommand`?

Reference:
[Select other image if file image not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513558/select-other-image-if-file-image-not-found?noredirect=1#comment1298864_513558)

if `C.jpg` not found, display `B.jpg`

if `C.jpg` found, display `A.jpg`

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\IfFileExists{Image/C.jpg}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Image/A.jpg}}{\includegraphics[width=8cm]{Image/B.jpg}}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's the use of this, but…

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\conditionalincludegraphics}[4][]{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}
    {\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}
    {\includegraphics[#1]{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}

\conditionalincludegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-c.jpg}{example-image-a}{example-image-b}

\bigskip

\conditionalincludegraphics[width=8cm]{doesnotexist.jpg}{example-image-a}{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

[image]